# difference between answers using .isna and (df==np.nan).sum().sum()

Tags: python, pandas

Aftre applying `df.fillna(df.mean())` to remove Nan values, I am getting different result with `df.isna().sum().sum()` and `(df==np.nan).sum().sum()`

with `(df==np.nan).sum().sum()` i am getting 0 
but with `df.isna().sum().sum()` i amgetting 33470

Comment: You can not compare with `np.nan`. `nan != nan`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`. Strictly speaking, the equality relation of a floating point number, is not an [*equivalence relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), since it is not entirely *reflexive*.

Indeed, if we for example compare `np.nan` with `np.nan`, we get:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

That is the main reason why `.isna()` exists in the first place.

If we for example make a dataframe that only consists out of `NaN`s, we see that `df.isna()` and `df == np.nan` give different answers:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan]*5, 'b': [np.nan]*5})
>>> df
    a   b
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
>>> df.isna()
      a     b
0  True  True
1  True  True
2  True  True
3  True  True
4  True  True
>>> df == np.nan
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

`isna()` method detects missing values, whereas when we do `df==np.nan` this always returns false since when you compare `np.nan == np.nan` the result is always False.

Example:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
    False

>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, np.nan], 'col2': [3, 4]})
>>> df
    col1    col2
  0  1.0       3
  1  NaN       4


>>> df.isnull().sum().sum()
    1

>>> (df==np.nan).sum().sum()
    0
```